# Deserialize custom exception from Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I return custom exceptions from WebApi through HttpResponseException. For example:

```
//Base class for all custom app exceptions
public class MyAppException : Exception {}

//Custom exceptions
public class MyCustomException1 : MyAppException { //custom properties}
public class MyCustomException2 : MyAppException { //other custom properties}
```

The client is a HttpClient and the message returned looks something like this:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Exception of type 'MyApp.Exceptions.MyCustomException1 ' was thrown.","ExceptionType":"MyApp.Exceptions.MyCustomException1 ","StackTrace":null}
```

Here there are 2 problems:

1. The properties for the custom exception are not in the message
2. The response message cannot be deserialized into a custom exception

Is there a way to deserialize the message into the correct exception?

Comment: You can create own custom converter (with Newtonsoft JSON) that deserializes exception basing on `ExceptionType` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Custom model binder` to analyze `ExceptionType` property to create instance of proper exception.
Please take a look at this working [Github sample](https://github.com/maxbrodin/custom-dynamic-binder/)

**EDITED**

Comment: I would like to deserialize the response message into one of my custom exceptions.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question, edited answer, please take a look